# Selecting R matrix values by blocks

Tags: r

I have a matrix of the form:

```
[,1] [,2]
1    0
100  0
200  1
300  1
400  1
500  0
600  0
700  1
800  1
900  1
```

I am trying to make an R script that selects at least 3 continuous "1" values on column 2, for example, retrieving

```
200  1
300  1
400  1
700  1
800  1
900  1
```

but cannot find an easy way to do it. Has anyone encountered a problem like this one? I'd be really grateful!!! Thanks!!!

Comment: Your example doesn't reflect the complexity of this task. Because here `dat[dat[,2] == 1, ]` will do it. Add for example two consecutive "one" or just one after a zero.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly my problem. Selecting the 1's is not a deal, but continuous 1's is where I get stuck :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `rle` and `inverse.rle` as follows:

```
r <- rle(mat[, 2])
r$values[r$values != 1 | r$lengths < 3] <- 0
keep <- as.logical(inverse.rle(r))
mat[keep, ]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `rle`. Say your matrix is `M` and your column of interest is `2`, then you can create a filter using this:

```
filter <- with(rle(M[,2]), rep(lengths>=3 & values==1, lengths))
```

Then filter the matrix using

```
M[filter,]
```

Comment: same idea, I like the use of `rep` as an alternative to `inverse.rle`.